# HTMX one hx-post form not working in a Django project

Tags: django, django-forms, htmx

In my Django portfolio project, I'm stuck with one weird bug. If you like puzzles, please read... On a page with a ListView (in which I already use HTMX), a button triggers a drawer/modal in which the logged in user can talk to ChatGPT (for films recommendations). It worked fine, until one day, for no apparent reason it stopped working a few days later (I didn't touch that part of the code, I was actually getting ready to send it to GitHub and find a host). The messages were not appearing in the textbox anymore. After hours of debugging (listening to ChatGPT telling me "your code seems ok"), I figured that the problem was coming from HTMX : the ChatGPT part works, I receive the messages (visible in the terminal), and if I don't use HTMX, the conversation appears in the textbox. Now, the problem thickens as I have the EXACT same code in an other project that works. I even changed all the little details of that previous project to match the new one, in order to see when will it stop working. It works. So, the hx-post doesn't work, but it does in the rest of the website and in other projects. Using debug tools didn't help.

Here is the simple view :

```
@login_required
def conversation_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_message = request.POST.get("user_message")
        context.append({"role": "user", "content": f"{user_message}"})
        conversation.append(user_message)
        bot_response = get_bot_response(context)
        context.append(
            {"role": "assistant", "content": f"{bot_response}"})
        conversation.append(bot_response)
        print(conversation)
    return render(request, "includes/chatgpt-drawer.html", {"chatgptmessages": conversation})
```

Here is the HTML of the drawer :

```
<div **id="chatgpt"** x-show="showDrawer" @click.outside="showDrawer = false" class="fixed top-16 right-0 z-50 h-screen p-4 overflow-y-auto bg-white w-2/3 lg:w-1/3 dark:bg-gray-800 ease-in-out -translate-x-full">
  <h3 class="text-center my-4 text-xl font-semibold">Meet <span class="text-red-600">Horrobot</span> !</h3>
  <button @click="showDrawer = false" type="button" class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 absolute top-2.5 end-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" >
    <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
      <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"/>
    </svg>
    <span class="sr-only">Close menu</span>
  </button>
  <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-600 pt-5 pb-4 px-8">
      <div class="mt-3 text-left">
          <p>Just say hello and ask for any recommendations concerning our catalog. Or just say hello. Please don't ask anything else, as it will not answer anyway. You must be logged in to talk to Horrorbot.</p>
          <div class="mt-3">
            <!-- Conversation Text Area -->
            <div class="border p-4 h-[400px] overflow-y-auto">
              <ul class="text-gray-950">
                {% for message in chatgptmessages %}
                <li class="list-none mb-2">{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <**form hx-post="{% url 'conversation' %}" hx-target="#chatgpt"**>
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="m-auto py-3 flex">
                <input type="text" name="user_message" class="w-4/5 text-gray-950" required>
                <button type="submit" class="bg-gray-950 text-gray-100 px-4 py-3 w-1/5">Chat</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the hx-target is set to the whole drawer, as I did in other projects.

Here is what I get in the terminal :

```
[05/Jan/2024 17:59:35] "GET /films/ HTTP/1.1" 200 62732
[05/Jan/2024 17:59:35] "GET /static/css/dist/styles.css?v=1704477575 HTTP/1.1" 200 49419
['hello', "Hello, horror fan! What can I do for you? If you have any questions or if you're looking for horror film recommendations, feel free to ask!", 'hello', 'Hello again! How can I assist you today? Are you looking for horror film recommendations or do you have any questions about horror cinema?', 'hello', 'Hello once more! How can I assist you today? Are you interested in discussing horror films or do you have any specific questions or requests?', 'hello', 'Hello again! How can I assist you today? Are you looking for horror film recommendations or do you have any questions about horror cinema?']
[05/Jan/2024 17:59:50] "POST /conversation/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3074
```

I keep on posting hello, it works as you can see, but the html refresh doesn't work. The HTML page doesn't change, the word "hello" stays in the input part. The debug thing is Django Debug Toolbar. The problem was there before adding it. It looks similar to what I get in the other project.

Obviously, I did try many variants, changing the code, making it clearer, changing the names of variables or the files, etc. The problem persists. I have restarted this project 3 times because of various bugs, but now I'm close to the end and just want to resolve this issue.

If someone has a hint, please answer me !

Comment: From your code, it looks like the content is swapped inside the `#chatgpt` div (due to innerHTML being used by default), which I can imagine may cause some issues.
Can you try adding `hx-swap="outerHTML"` to you form tag and see if that helps?

Comment: Thank you for answering. It doesn't change anything, as the swap never occurred. When I press the button, nothing happens front-end. The word I type doesn't even disappears, it's like the button doesn't work (but it does, as I do receive an answer from ChatGPT, that I can see in the terminal). This is honestly the weirdest bug i've ever seen. especially that it used to work fine.

Comment: @VoyageurZen did you ever find a working solution for your problem? I am currently experiencing the same issue and any advice would be greatly appreciated.